# Midori browser sidebar size

Tags: ubuntu, browser, webkit

I'm about to change to Midori browser, but I have a strange bug: the size of the sidebar does not seem to be saved, it decides its size on an unknown factor. Before adding a user-style, it was always the smallest, now it takes 1/3d of my screen.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

System: Linux Mint 10, 2.6.36 kernel, Midori 0.4.1 from ppa.